# Unity health and armor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello so i have a health and armor script and wen i shoot and i have lets say 
20 armor and 100 health after 2 shots that take 10 damage so you expect your armor to be 0 and you health 100 but wen i do it my armor is 0 and my health 90 i dont know how to avoid it to take damage after my armor is 0 or less i want to fix that 
here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health_Armor : MonoBehaviour {
    public float health;
    public float armor;




    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        health = 100f;
        armor = 20f;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        Max_Min_Stats();

    }

    private void Max_Min_Stats()
    {        
        if(health >= 100f)
        {
            health = 100f;
        }

        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            health = 0f;
        }

        if (armor >= 100f)
        {
            armor = 100f;
        }

        if (armor <= 0f)
        {
            armor = 0f;
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        armor -= amount;
        if (armor <= 0f)
        {
            health -= amount;
            if (health <= 0f)
            {
                Death();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Death()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `armor -= amount` and watch what happens.

Comment: yea i know it takes out the armor and then because its 0 it will take health wiht that amouth how can i fix that

Comment: I just want to know to fix it and how to avoid in in future @jdphenix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of things that you need to keep track of for this calculation.

- The damage applied to armor.
- How much damage is left to be dealt. If the damage is 10, you want to be able to deal 5 damage to armor and 5 to health.

  ```
  // Save the amount of damage remaining off. 
  var damageLeft = amount;
  if (armor > 0) { // Should armor damage be calculated?
      var armorDamage = Math.min(damageLeft, armor);
      armor -= armorDamage; 
      damageLeft -= armorDamage;
  } 

  if (damageLeft > 0) {
      health -= damageLeft;
  }

  if (health <= 0) {
      // die gory death
  }
  ```

Comment: That's significantly simpler then, just remove the code that tracks the damage remaining, check for `armor > 0` and apply the damage to armor if true, else apply the damage to health. Also - it would be good to update your question with these new details.

Comment: just a  question what are we doing actually with the math.min in that way how is it used

Comment: If order to know how much damage to apply to the armor, you have to make sure to not apply excess damage to armor that should be applied to health. Otherwise, you'd end up with damage that should be applied to health being lost.

Answer (score 3):

Try to think about what's actually happening as a result of the code, instead of the code itself.

Assuming amount = 10...

Health = 100, Armor = 20.

TakeDamage() -> Decrease armor by 10 -> New value is 10 -> is Armor less than or equal to 0? No. Done.

Health = 100, Armor = 10

TakeDamage() -> Decrease armor by 10 -> new value is 0 -> is Armor less than or equal to 0? -> Yes. -> Decrease health by 10.

How can this be fixed? Well, if you put the if statement *before* you subtract from your armor, then armor becomes 0 *after* checking if it's 0 to subtract from health.

tl;dr - subtract the amount from armor *after* you have evaluated the if.

edit: Jdphenix posted a method which you could consider implementing. In your current implementation if you have 5 armor and 100hp, and take 10 damage, then armor becomes 0, and health stays at 100, so you lose 5 damage to the abyss. Jdphenix's way prevents this from happening, and instead health will become 95 and armor will become 0, and the remainder is not lost.